# Practice Chat APP for class

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to programming just needed some help on why my `ChatApp` is messing up.

I'm trying to get my written server to send to the client `"Robot: (client's username)` connected" when a person logs on.

I've tried to do it for the past four hours in class, Thanks for your time.

My github is https://github.com/Liangalvin/ChatApp

The DOM displays `"Robot: [object object] connected"`, instead of it being the username of the connected client.

Answer (score 0):

So presumably you have a string that looks like:

```
"Robot: "+someVar+" connected".
```

It should be

```
"Robot: "+someVar.someProperty+" connected"
```

so `console.log(somevar)` and see what you got in there

Comment: comes back with the hash of {"name":"Robot","newMessage":"[object Object] connected","color":"black"} on the server

Comment: ok, the robots name is robot? your string should probably be `"Robot: "+someVar.name+" connected" `

Comment: sorry it actually dosent show anything, I had another consolelog for the parameter... "someVar is not defined"

Comment: well, I don't literally mean `someVar` you should replace `someVar` with the name of your variable

Comment: Yeah... I know I just stuck it in like that because I used a profanity as a variable from my frustrations... but I stuck the parameter in, I think it might actually be the websocket(clients) info that is serialized by JSON... but my logic is that this is going to be sent into the hash, then the hash is stringifed with JSON and passed back into the client where the information is parsed and shown in my chatroom... the problem is where its coming back as [object object]... ALSO! does it matter that it's being passed from the prompt?

Comment: i also tried forgot to mention i tried to do it as a hash from the client side... but it comes back as "undefined connected"